# Fill vector through loop in r

Tags: r, loops, vector

I'm trying to fill a a vector through a loop in R.

```
# variables 
  vector1 <- c("aaaa", "bbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd")
  vector2 <- c("bbbb", "eeeee", "fffff", "ddddd")

  # function
  total <- numeric(length(vector1)*length(vector2))
  subtotal <- numeric(length(vector1))
  aux <- 0

  for(i in 1:length(vector2)){
    subtotal = mapply(levenshteinSim, vector1, vector2[[i]])
    total[(length(vector1)*aux)+1:length(vector1)*i] <- subtotal
    inc(aux) <- 1
  }
```

For 2 vectors with 4 lengths, i have a total vector with length 16.

However i got the following output:

```
> total [1]  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA NA  0 NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA  1
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The Levensthein function i got from RecordLinkage package, and inc function, from Hmisc package. The first compares two strings, and the other just increments value to some variable.

EDIT2: I'm using some strange functions, but my objetive is only to fill the total vector though the loop, with the subtotals values. Let's get some other example:

```
# variables
  vector1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
  vector2 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

  # function
  total <- numeric(length(vector1)*length(vector2))
  subtotal <- numeric(length(vector1))
  aux <- 0

  for(i in 1:length(vector2)){
    subtotal = mapply(paste, vector1, vector2[[i]])
    total[(length(vector1)*aux)+1:length(vector1)*i] <- subtotal
    aux <- aux + 1
    print(subtotal)
  }
```

I expected the following result: a vector Total with length 16, filled with the subtotals vectors from the loop. Something like this:

```
    a     b     c     d 
"a a" "b a" "c a" "d a" 
    a     b     c     d 
"a b" "b b" "c b" "d b" 
    a     b     c     d 
"a c" "b c" "c c" "d c" 
    a     b     c     d 
"a d" "b d" "c d" "d d"
```

However I got this: a vector with 28 positions, and many N/As:

```
 [1] "a a" "b a" "c a" "d a" "0"   "a b" "0"   "b b" "0"   "c b" "a c" "d b" "0"   "b c" "0"   "a d" "c c" NA    NA   
[20] "b d" NA    NA    NA    "c d" NA    NA    NA    "d d"
```

Comment: What is the function `levenshteinSim` ?

Comment: Its a function from CRAN package RecordLinkage. It compares two strings and gives the similarity of them. (eg: 1 similar, 0 not similar)

Comment: Try to clarify your objective! How are `total` and `subtotal` suppose to be filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the ':' operator having higher precedence than the other operators, try
adding brackets:

```
total[((length(vector1)*aux)+1):(length(vector1)*i)] <- subtotal
```

Alternatively, you might prefer to replace the whole code with:

```
as.vector(outer(vector1,vector2,paste))
```

Comment: Great! Also didn't knew about the outer. Thanks!